# Libgdx Screenshot method not working

Tags: libgdx, screenshot

A couple of weeks ago I implemented this method https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot
And it worked great with libgdx 1.3.1 . Now though I upgraded to 1.6.0 and it have stopped working. 
When the method is executed it freezes. I have it implemented on a button, and it gets stuck in "downclick" and nothing more happens.

```
private void saveScreenshot() {
    try{
        FileHandle fh;
        do{
            fh = new FileHandle(files.getLocalStoragePath() + "screenshot" + ".png");

        }while(fh.exists());

        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 130, true);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
        System.out.println("Path:" + fh.toString());

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
private Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown){

    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);
    w = pixmap.getWidth();
    h = pixmap.getHeight();
    if(yDown) {
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }

        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
    }
    return pixmap;
}

 btnArrow.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        //photoshop "save" and "back" on arrow/back image to clarify.
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            saveScreenshot();
            sharePhoto();

        }
    });
```

I share the image to facebook aswell. And this method is in AndroidLauncher of course and is passed through an interface. And here I fetch the screenshot:

```
public void sharePhoto() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    String filePath = (files.getLocalStoragePath() + "screenshot" + ".png");
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    Bitmap rotateBit = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


    //Starts sharing process
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(rotateBit)
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    share.show(content);

}
```

So what I believe may be the issue is libgdx have done changes on Pixmap class or Bitmap class of some sort. Since sharing a link through facebook on that button works fine.

I also printed the path as you can see in saveScreenshot() and it returns this

```
selinux_android_setcategory: no category for userid: 0, path: /data/data/com.sparc.tormt.android/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it stuck because this is an infinite loop if the file already exists:

```
do {
   fh = new FileHandle(files.getLocalStoragePath() + "screenshot" + ".png");
} while(fh.exists());
```

Comment: Yes it gets stuck. I read the docs, and it should overwrite the already existing image if there is one. But how do you suggest to do it? Cause it gets stuck as you say.

Comment: Just remove this loop?  I think the loop is a broken attempt at trying to find a "unique" name for the file, and should do something like: `var name = files.getLocalStoragePath() + "screenshot" + (i++) + ".png";` (Note the "i++" to make the name different on each iteration of the loop.  But I'm just guessing.)